# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./RandomWords"

Tags: reactjs

In my react application, i have 2 nested components. The parent is `RandomWords` and the child is `Word`.

Here is the parent (**Randomword**):

```
var things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
console.log(thing);

var Word = require('./Word');
var React = require('react');

    var RandomWords = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div >
             <h4>Type the below word </h4>
             <Word typeitem=thing/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

module.exports =RandomWords;
```

Line `<Word typeitem=thing/>` leads to the error like

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./RandomWords"
```

Meanwhile when i change it to the `<Word typeitem="Paper"/>`, the application works correctly.
**It seems that is has a problem with `thing`.**

But the problem is, i want to get a random word and put it in my `typeitem`.

Point: `word` is working correctly

```
var React = require('react');
var Word=React.createClass({
       render: function(){
            return(
              <div >
                   {this.props.typeitem}
              </div>
            );
  }
});

module.exports =Word;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Word typeitem={thing} />
```

Make sure your attribute values are either expressed as strings or surrounded by `{}`. This likely leads to a parse error, causing an error when trying to import.